# ASP.net html element onclickserver not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

i have `<ul>` that contains this elements :

```
<li><a id="testClick" href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSwitch_Click">Click This</a></li>
```

and that works, that html element can click on btnSwitch_Click on server side.
but i try something new,  i create html code from js, like this :

```
function updateDDLSheets()
{
    var ddlSheets = $('#ulSheetList');
    ddlSheets.empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dashboard.aspx/GetSheetItems",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (msg) {
            var txt = msg.d;
            var items = eval('(' + txt + ')');
            for (var ii = 0; ii < items.length; ii++) {
                ddlSheets.append('<li><a href=\"#\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"btnSwitch_Click\" class=\"ddlSheet\" data-sheet=\"' + items[ii].ID + '\" data-mod=\"' + items[ii].Mods_ID + '\">' + items[ii].Name + '</a></li>');

            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want this html element created by this js code can work like first html code, but onserverclick didnt work.
please help me why?
and how make onserverclick in that html element can work?

Comment: @Mate So what must i do? make that in server-side? how?

Comment: how about use : Sys.Application.add_load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create server-side control on client-side. If you need to create actual server-side control dynamically - you can do it in server-side C#/VB.NET (whatever you're using in your ASP.NET) code. But in this case you will have to create your LI elements on server as well.

Another possibility: Notice thats ASP.NET renders server-side control:

```
<a id="testClick" href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSwitch_Click">Click This</a>
```

as

```
<a id="testClick" href="javascript:__doPostBack('testClick','')">Click This</a>
```

in HTML.

You can try creating second element in your client-side "success" function. Completed with call to "__doPostBack" function.